# SQL server script to find table dependencies

Tags: sql-server, dependencies

I have about 500 tables across a number of servers/databases for which I need to write a script to identify dependencies. Basically these tables are undergoing changes in field size, etc. and we want to identify if any other objects - stored procedures, functions, views etc. that could be referencing them. This list is not final and could be growing as well.
I found the following two ways to find dependencies:

```
--Method 1:
sp_depends 'Your_tableName'
GO

-- Method 2:Using DMV sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('Your_tableName', 'OBJECT');
GO
```

My question is what is the best possible way to achieve this? 
Where to put that list so that I could use a while loop to read all the list of tables and list the dependencies?
I cannot create SQL tables on production database for table names that are being changed so that I could read in a WHILE loop. 
Also, I only have access to SSMS.
Please advise!

P.S.  Please let me know if there is a way to check dependencies on linked servers

Answer (score 0):

***Try bellow script to show your requested result:***

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(N'Your_tableName' , 'OBJECT')
```

Answer (score -1):

I've run into the same issue previously.  Your 2nd method above is probably better, but beware that it pulls some of that relationship data from built-in system views which may have cached data, so work with your dba admin if you're don't think it's returning with most recent changes.  I'll update post if I find the script I used for this.